# React.js using context api to implement the dark/light theme, is it possible to get data in App component when I am using contextprovider?

Tags: themes, reactjs, react-context

I am using the context api to give my application the toggling ability between the dark/light mode, I managed to toggle the mode in all the children components of ***App*** component but when I tried to implement it to the component  itself I failed I guess this related the fact the I am using the contextProvider within this component, code below for  :

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './App.module.css'
import { Card, CountryPicker, Chart } from './components/index'
import { fetchData } from './api/index'
import ThemeContextProvider, { ThemeContext } from './contexts/ThemeContext'
import ToggleTheme from './components/ToggleTheme/ToggleTheme'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext

  state = {
    data: {},
    country: '',
  }
  handleCountryChange = async (country) => {
    // console.log(country)
    const Data = await fetchData(country)
    // console.log(Data)
    this.setState({ data: Data, country })
    // console.log(this.state.data, this.state.country)
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fetchData();
    this.setState({ data })

  }
  render() {
    const { data, country } = this.state;
    // problem here
    const { isLightTheme, dark, light } = this.context;

    return (
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <div className={styles.container}  >
          <ToggleTheme />
          <Card data={data} />
          <CountryPicker handleCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange} />
          <Chart data={data} country={country} />
        </div>
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,the solution was very simple, just importing the `App` component into other component`Main` and wrapping it with `<ContextProvider></ContextProvider>` and import in the `index.js`